# A question about the additive group of the $p$-adic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $J_p$ be the additive group of the $p$-adic integers. I know that it is torsion-free. I'm not pretty confortable with $p$-adic.

Is it possible to find a direct sum of infinitely many cyclic subgroup in $J_p$? (essentially I'm asking if they have finite special rank or not).

**EDIT**

I find out on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) that they effectively have infinite rank. But I still cannot find that direct sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Complete rewrite:**

For this, you need to look at the fraction field $\Bbb Q_p$ of the $p$-adic integer ring $\Bbb Z_p$. It’s a vector-space over $\Bbb Q$, and according to a well-known theorem depending on the Axiom of Choice, there’s a $\Bbb Q$-basis of this vector space. Since $\Bbb Q_p$ is uncountable, the basis must be uncountable as well. For each $\beta$ in the basis, there’s a rational number $\lambda_\beta$ such that $\lambda_\beta\beta\in\Bbb Z_p$. Now take the (uncountably-indexed) direct sum
$\bigoplus_\beta\lambda_\beta\beta\,\Bbb Z$. There you are.

Comment: I’m finally beginning to see your point. I’ll modify my answer heavily.

Comment: Is it obvious that for $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ there is $\lambda_\beta \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\lambda_\beta \beta \in \mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: @PavelC, yes, indeed, in fact you can even take $\lambda=p^m$ in such a way that $\lambda\beta$ is a $p$-adic unit, i.e. has $p$-adic absolute value equal to $1$.